# Mersenne, Fibonacci... are there other cases in which the existence of a given prime implies the existence of another prime?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Thinking about why it seems impossible to find a case in which the existence of a given prime implies the existence of another bigger prime, I tried to make a list of cases in which knowing that a number is prime then automatically we know that other one is prime. So far I just can recall two well known non-trivial situations:

> 1. Mersenne numbers, if $p=2^n-1$ is prime then $n$ is prime as well. The opposite is not true.
> 2. Fibonacci numbers, if $p=F_n$ is prime then $n$ is prime as well. The opposite is not true.

In both cases $n$ is smaller than $p$.

I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Did I forget more cases?
> 2. It seems that the existence of the bigger prime $p$ implies the existence of the smaller prime $n$ but I can not recall any cases in which a **single** (only one required) smaller prime $n$ implies that a bigger prime $p$ automatically exists. Are there any papers regarding that impossibility? Are there such cases?
>    Thank you!

Update 16/02/2016: as kindly explained in the comments by @DanielFischer and answer by @TitoPiezasIII, there are generalizations of both the Mersenne and Fibonacci numbers that are also part of the list.

Comment: 2. If you found a case where primes implied larger primes, you would have a prime generator, which nobody has currently found.

Comment: If the existence of small primes implied the existence of larger primes, then the restrictions on large-prime prizes would have to be much more arcane than just digit count. However, there are existence results such as [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Comment: The least prime divisor of $p_0\cdots p_k+1$, where the $p_i$ are the first $k+1$ primes, is a larger prime.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you for the feedback... sorry do you mean $p_0 \cdot ... \cdot p_k$ as the primorial? please may I ask for an specific example?

Comment: Yes, the smallest prime factor of a primorial plus $1$. So the numbers are $3, 7, 31, 211, \dots$.  They are not necessarily equal to $p_0\cdot p_k+$, for that number need not be prime.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh yes, that is a demonstration of the infinity of prime numbers, but my question is more specific, when you know the prime p you already know automatically the value of the other linked prime n. In your example you need to know more than one prime and you still do not know automaticaly the value of the greater prime associated to it. My question in more "biyective" 1:1 one prime implies another bigger prime.

Comment: As the comment say above, any such bijective correspondence is unlikely (as it would allow to generate primes on demand), unless the actual mapping is actually uncomputable or not efficiently computable (under standard assumptions).

Comment: @ClementC. understood thank you! (btw. sorry for my typo, 'bijective') I was also interested on the existence of more relationships like the ones I mentioned, Fibonacci and Mersenne... probably only those two exist... I wonder if there are others of that type.

Comment: @ElliotG the closest thing similar to a prime generator is Mill's constant (caveat: requires Riemann Hypothesis to be true for accuracy) but it does not use a previous prime except in the detail that the formula requires $3$ as the exponent applied to the constant $A^{3^n}$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant

Comment: Regarding the "more cases", we have a generalisation of the Mersenne numbers situation: given $a > 1$, if $\dfrac{a^n-1}{a-1}$ is prime, then $n$ is prime. (Not super interesting, but, well …)

Comment: I think "prime generator", "know automatically", "efficiently computable", etc. all are best defined as a $DTIME((\log{n})^k)$ algorithm that computes a prime larger than $n$.  It is unknown if one exists.  However, simply counting up from $n$ and testing for primality using the AKS primality test until the first prime larger than $n$ is found may be such an algorithm, this is implied by Cramér's conjecture.

Comment: As Andre Nicolas (above) and Euclid (about 24 centuries ago) there are many ways to find a prime greater than the primr p. But not necessarily efficient ways.

Comment: @user254665 agreed, my question was focused on 'bijections', is about primes $p$ that due to their properties are related to another prime $n$ that is 'automatically' known if it is demonstrated that $p$ is prime, like in the cases I mention, Mersenne and Fibonacci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be ***infinitely*** more such sequences.

> **I.** Particular

Starting with $n=0$, note that for the ***Fibonacci numbers***,

$$F_n = 0,1,1,2,\color{red}3,5,8,13,\dots\tag1$$

and $F_4=3$ does ***not*** have a prime index. Similarly for the ***Jacobsthal numbers***,

$$J_n = 0, 1, 1, 3, \color{red}5, 11, 21, 43,\dots\tag2$$

with the similar exception $J_4=5$. (Indices for prime $J_n$ is [A107036](https://oeis.org/A107036).). We also have the ***Pell numbers***,

$$P_n = 0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169,\dots\tag3$$

and if $P_n$ is prime, then $n$ is prime.

> **II.** General

If we define the first family of the [*Lucas sequence*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasSequence.html),

$$U_n(P,Q) \equiv \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$$

where $a,b$ are the roots of $x^2-Px+Q=0$, then,

$$U_n(1,-1) = \text{Fibonacci}\\
U_n(1,-2) = \text{Jacobsthal}\\
U_n(1,-3) = \text{A006130}\\
\vdots\\
U_n(2,-1) = \text{Pell}\\
U_n(3,-1) = \text{A006190}\\\vdots$$

so presumably appropriate members of the family behave similarly.

Comment: thank you for the answer... that is right, when I wrote in my question about Mersenne and Fibonacci I forgot the generalizations and similar sequences. It seems so far that there are two kind of 'families', one related with 'exponentiation' (Mersenne-like) and other related with 'accumulation' (Fibonacci-Lucas et al). Btw the negative was not mine.

Comment: @iadvd: Ok. **P.S.** Note the exception $U_4 = P(P^2-2Q)$, so for $P=1$ may yield a prime (like $F_4 = 3)$ even though the index $n=4$ is not prime.

Answer (score 3):

There is a prime-generating formula, but not a practical one.

Ghandhi's formula for the next prime: Let $Q$ be the product of the primes less than the odd prime $p$.(If $p=3$ then $Q=2.$)$$\text {Let }\quad S=-\frac {1}{2}+\sum_{d|Q}\frac {\mu (d)}{2^d-1}$$ where $\mu$ is the Mobius function.$$\text {Then }\quad 1<2^pS<2.$$ Since $2^{p-1}<1$ and $2<2^{p+1}$ this uniquely defines the natural number $p$.

To prove it write each term $\mu (d)/(2^d-1)=\mu (d)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n d}.$ Collect powers of $2$ in the sum over $d|Q.$ Using the property of $\mu$ that $\sum_{e|n}\mu(e)=0$ for $n>1$ we obtain $$S=\sum_{n\in T}2^{-n}$$ where $T=\{m:m>1\land \gcd (m,Q)=1\}.$  From the def'n of $Q$ we have $\min T=p$, and all members of $T$ are odd, so $$2^{-p}<S\leq 2^{-p}(1+1/2^2+1/2^4+...)=2^{-p}(4/3)<2^{1-p}.$$

This is about as inefficient a way as possible for generating primes.E.g. to to find the least prime greater than $1,000,000$ with this formula, you need to know all the primes less than $1,000,000$, and sum all the terms in the formula. Since there are about $72,000$ primes below $1,000,000$ this means adding about $2^{72,000}$ terms to get $S$.

Comment: +1 for the cool explanation, I did not know this formula. And my apologies because my question was probably badly written (English is not my native language) I have specified the question to clarify: point 2 states now more clearly: "I can not recall any cases in which a single (only one required) smaller prime n implies that a bigger prime p automatically exists"

Comment: I had no trouble with understanding your Q. This was the nearest to an answer that I can do. I saw Ghandhi's formula in a very old issue of American Math'l Monthly, where it  was proven without the use of power series, which seemed  to me to be an awkward method.